# Multiple Web APIs in one project?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So, we're migrating from web services to web APIs. We'll be using VS 2015 with .NET and MVC 5 - our plan was to have all of our web APIs in one project (where obviously each controller would be a separate API). Then we were going to host the API on an intranet site (i.e. webapis.company.com) and just call the API / method by route.

Would this be considered bad practice? If so, what would be the best way to go about splitting up our APIs?

Comment: How many methods would be in each controller? Maybe I don't understand the question but what you're describing seems typical. In every WebAPI project I've worked with, we have multiple controllers each containing one or more get, post methods, etc.

Comment: Each controller will hold approximately 2 - 10 methods. So say I have an API for emails. All the methods for emails would be in the EmailController. But let's also say I want another API that deals with Employees. So I would throw those in the EmployeeController in the same project. So I guess what I'm asking is should I split these up in to different projects in the same solution? Basically asking if it's bad practice. But it seems like from what you're saying it's perfectly fine to have them all in one solution, right?

Comment: Yeah in that scenario I think one project makes the most sense.

Comment: @Woodchipper When would it not make sense?

Comment: @MZawg Mainly around security and scalability. If you had an internal and public api, I'd host those in two separate environments. Around scaling it may make sense to break up APIs into functional business areas (billing, reporting, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yeah in that scenario I think one project makes the most sense.

–  Mike Sheehan

Thank you!